# Most frequent ngrams in a CSV using nltk

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I have a csv file with million+ tweets. I have sanitized the data and I want to **find the most frequent 2 / 3 / 4 word phrases that occur across the file**.

I am importing the csv as a list. It is important that bigrams / trigrams are generated within the line of list. i. e.
for a list:
'Sally is great'
'Bob is not'

Bigrams will be 
'Sally is', 'is great', 'Bob is', 'is not'

And **not** 'great Bob'
(i. e. rows should not be concatenated)

Here's the code:

```
#import necessary packages
#read csv
with open("small_sample.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    dfl = list(reader)

#import ngrams function
from nltk import ngrams
#store bigrams in string_bigrams
string_bigrams=''
n=2
for line in dfl:
    string_bigrams += ngrams(str(line).split(),n)
```

**edit**
Since I cannot use += with generator object and converting the ngrams to string does not give required results, i used itertools.chain to add to the generator object.

updated code:

```
for line in dfl:
    string_bigrams 
    =itertools.chain(string_bigrams,ngrams(str(line).split(),n))
```

However, the output here has '[' concatenated to it.
i. e. if list is saved as ['Sally is great','Bob is not']
string_bigrams returns

```
("['Sally", 'is')
('is', "great']")
("['Bob", 'is')
('is', "not']")
```

Expected output is

```
('Sally', 'is')
('is', 'great')
('Bob', 'is')
('is', 'not')
```

Why are the [] appended?

Comment: There are a lost of confusing/undefined things in your problem. How many of the most frequent do you want? are you only taking whitespace-delimited ngrams?

Comment: @erip # of most frequent will depend on data. i. e. i might end up taking top 10-20% of total bigrams depending on frequency distribution. so effectively, i would need all ngrams sorted by frequency in decreasing order. and yes, looking at only whitespace delimited ngrams

Comment: I hope your machine has a lot of memory for >= 1M tweets! Can you show the first couple lines of your csv file?

Comment: i have 32 gb ram, i am hoping that would be good enough

Comment: What kind of "issues" are you facing with the ngram function? If your programs are with ngrams, what does the manner of reading the CSV have to do with it? Your question reads like "write my code, I have no clue but I don't want to admit it." If that's an unfair impression, please clarify your question.

Comment: @alexis  
i am fairly new to python, so i am able to execute the pieces separately, but not able to put them together. i got the bigrams using ngram(input, n) and their frequency as well but this is for a string. not sure how to iterate through the list. so either i sift through the list and keep adding ngrams or use another way to store the csv which works better with the function. i couldn't find much on both despite searching. i don't know if that sounds like write my code.

Comment: Can you include some data from your CSV that gives you this error? When I run your example with ['Sally is great','Bob is not'], I get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ("['Sally", 'is')
> ('is', "great']")
> ```
>
> Why are the [] appended?

It's not just the brackets, you also have stray quotes. This clearly comes from applying `str` to a list, which novice Python programmers often do to paper over an error instead of figuring out where it's coming from.

Where it's coming from must be this: Your "csv file" doesn't actually have  columns, it's just got one message per line. But the `csv` module always returns the contents of each row as a *list* of columns, meaning that the variable `line` is a one-element list that looks like this:

```
['Sally is great']
```

To fix the problem, initialize `string_bigrams` to an empty *list* and change this

```
string_bigrams += ngrams(str(line).split(),n)
```

to this:

```
string_bigrams.extend( ngrams(line[0].split(), n) )
```

And never, ever apply `str` to a list again.